# A problem about VSCode for setting Python debuging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

vs code version:1.29.1（1.29.1）

python version:3.6.5

---

Launch.json:

```
     {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "pythonPath":"${config.python.pythonPath}", 
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "console": "none",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ],
        "env": {"name":"value"}
    }
```

workspacesettings:

```
     {
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python",
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true
     }
```

---

[Extensions I downloaded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmrp3.png)

---

When I test for debugging, I got failed.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2uVi.png)

---

It's said "You need to select a Python interpreter before you start debugging".
But I actually choice one version shows in the lower left corner.

Any part is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation that has been given here in the website of VS Code may be helpful. Did you try getting reference from here?
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Answer (score 1):

I edit as the code below and it works!!

```
{
"name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${file}",
"console": "integratedTerminal",
"stopOnEntry": true
}
```